# numpy: Efficient way to use a 1D array as an index into 2D array

Tags: numpy, vectorization

```
X.shape == (10,4)
y.shape == (10)
```

I'd like to produce `M`, where each entry in M is defined as `M[r,c] == X[r, y[r]]`; that is, use `y` to index into the appropriate column of `X`.

How can I do this efficiently (without loops)?

`M` could have a single column, though eventually I need to broadcast it so that it has the same shape as `X`.  `c` starts from the first col of `X` (0) and goes to the last (9).

Comment: What's the expected shape for `M`? How is that `c` setup?

Answer (score 2):

Just do :

```
X=np.arange(40).reshape(10,4)
Y=np.random.randint(0,4,10)

M=X[range(10),Y]
```

for

```
In [8]: X
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39]])

In [9]: Y
Out[9]: array([1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1])

In [10]: M
Out[10]: array([ 1,  5, 11, 15, 17, 22, 26, 31, 34, 37])
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain how this works? I've found it hard to distinguish numpy's broadcasting and arracy access from voodoo.

Comment: Also: That `range` is a Python object, and, for very large arrays (which I'm using), will be slow.  Can we do it using a Numpy array instead?

Comment: But `np.array(range(100000))` is much slower than `np.arange(100000)`, even on python3. Wouldn't be hard to fix that in numpy though

Comment: `X[np.arange(10),Y]` is faster - though it really should be tested on much larger arrays.

Comment: @SRobertames : Python indexing is described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).